# How to add cursor position after adding a component to content-editable div

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, range, cursor

I have inserted the component on a click of a button. Now I want the cursor position after my child component added into the parent div. I am attaching a sandbox link, it contains the code I have done so far.
[SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-forked-k4rni?file=/App.vue)

code:

```
var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(Child);
  var instance = new ComponentClass();
  instance.$mount(); // pass nothing

  var editableDiv = this.$refs.editor;
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  // check that we are in content editable div
  if (sel.getRangeAt(0).endContainer.parentNode.id === "editor") {
    range.insertNode(instance.$el);
    range.setStartAfter(instance.$el);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    editableDiv.focus();
```

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for replying, I have added the code in the question. I have added the focus to the parent div, but it didn't work. What I want to do is add the cursor next to the new component added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was I have applied a "display:flex" property to the parent div and now display: "inline-block" helped and its done. Now just applying focus to the main div, I get the the cursor position after the component added.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a problem with WebKit-specific because it didn't happen in Edge or firefox.
when the page loades, click anywhere else and then click the button and you'll see that the error won't happen.
you can check rangeCount before using getRangeAt.
e.g:

```
var sel = window.getSelection && window.getSelection();
    if (sel && sel.rangeCount > 0) {// Your code here //}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it help. But what I found is I have applied display:flex on the parent div and by applying display: inline-block. It worked fine.